# html -how to use english-fonts for russian letters?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've downloaded comfortaa font files and css from localfont.com web-site.Then,in main.css i used

```
 @font-face {       
  font-family: 'Comfortaa-regular';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Comfortaa'),
       local('Comfortaa-regular'),
       url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/Comfortaa-regular/Comfortaa-regular.svg#Comfortaa') format('svg');}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 ,h6{
    color: #6d6d6d;
    font-family: "Comfortaa-700", arial;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

The problem is

1)When i use this code for english letters,everything works well,but in case of russian letters this font doesn't work.How can i use this font for russian characters ?

2)What is the difference between downloading the necessary font files/like i did here/ and using `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&subset=cyrillic,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` ,which is used in case of google fonts.

3)Which is the best way to use fonts in web page?

Comment: does it have the russian symbols?

Comment: here is the link https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Script:cyrillic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cyrillic Comfortaa should work via Google API, exactly as you suggest:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&subset=latin,cyrillic">
```

I prefer this way because the user might have this font already cached from previous sessions with Google fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your help,but i have a question.What will happen if the user didn't have cached that font ? Will Google API fonts work in opera,internet explorer and other web-browsers?

Comment: Yes, it should just pull it from the Google server, if the user has Internet connection